# subtotal for an index from a pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need subtotal for the index **PC** in the pivot table. i have the below code for my output

`data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC, 'Geo', 'Comp'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2'], columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)`

`data_frame1 = data_frame1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`
   
`tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a!= 'All' else (a,b) for a,b in data_frame1.columns]`
   
`data_frame1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)`

**output:**

```
              jan-19               Feb-19
            Bill1 Bill2     Bill1 Bill2     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1.28        1    1.28
B  US    OP   1     1.28        1    1.28
C  Can   OV   1     1.28        1    1.28
```

**Desired Output**

```
               jan-19              Feb-19
            Bill1 Bill2     Bill1 Bill2     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1.28        1    1.28
       Total  1     1.28        1    1.28
B  US    OP   1     1.28        1    1.28
       Total  1     1.28        1    1.28  
C  Can   OV   1     1.28        1    1.28
       Total  1     1.28        1    1.28
```

[image: data_frame1.to_excel()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#change sample data for added 1 row for check if working sum
print (df)
            jan-19       Feb-19      
             Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2
PC Geo Comp                          
A  Ind OS        1  1.28      1  1.28
       OP        8  2.00      1  1.00
B  US  OV        1  1.28      1  1.28
C  Can OV        1  1.28      1  1.28
```

Here is problem with correct sorting `Total` to end of each groups, so converted third level to [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html) with set order - last value is `Total`:

```
lev = df.index.get_level_values(2)
cat =  lev.unique().tolist() + ['Total']

df.index = [df.index.get_level_values(0), 
            df.index.get_level_values(1), 
            pd.CategoricalIndex(lev, categories=cat, ordered=True)]
```

Then `sum` values per first and second level (`PC`,`Geo`) and add `Total` values to third level:

```
df1 = df.sum(level=[0,1]).assign(name='Total').set_index('name', append=True)
```

Then add to original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) - because `ordered Categorical` here `Total` is in the end of groups:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index()
print (df)
             jan-19       Feb-19      
              Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2
PC Geo Comp                           
A  Ind OS         1  1.28      1  1.28
       OP         8  2.00      1  1.00
       Total      9  3.28      2  2.28
B  US  OV         1  1.28      1  1.28
       Total      1  1.28      1  1.28
C  Can OV         1  1.28      1  1.28
       Total      1  1.28      1  1.28
```